# Checkbox Take Value From Textbox

Tags: php, checkbox, textbox

I have a problem to combine the checkbox and textbox values. Here my snipet code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id_staf[]" value="query from database">
<input type="text" name="note[]" value="any text entered">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_staf[]" value="query from database">
<input type="text" name="note[]" value="any text entered">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_staf[]" value="query from database">
<input type="text" name="note[]" value="any text entered">
<br>
```

this is my php code to process that form:

```
$array_id_staf = $_POST['id_staf'];
$array_note= $_POST['note'];

for($a = 0; $a < count($array_id_staf); ++$a) {
echo $query1 = "UPDATE peserta SET note='$array_note[$a]' WHERE id= '$array_id_staf[$a]'<br>debugging";
//----------------------testing---------------------------@mysql_query($query1); // hold first for debugging
} // Closing for
```

if all checkbox were checked, the result os going fine. But if the second and 3rd were checked, array $array_note become wrong.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag `Php` Zone in your question.